# Can I set the horizontal scroll offset in Vim?

Tags: vim, vimrc

I would like to always see a little bit of context when the lines are to long, like:

```
set scrolloff=5
```

Is possible?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

See "`:help 'sidescrolloff'`".  It works the same as `'scrolloff'`, only vertically, so you can do:

```
set sidescrolloff=5
```

Comment: Can I set that based on percentage of the current terminal width?

Comment: @theonlygusti You could write a function to compute the absolute number, but other than that, no.